# Гложить - глагол исключение?

Tags: окончания, инфинитив

Гложить - инфинитив, форма в 3-м лице - гложет, в окончании буква е, но инфинитив заканчивается на -ить. Значит глагол гложить исключение?

Comment: Строго говоря, в принятом там ответе лишь высказаны полезные догадки, достойные дальнейшего обсуждения.

Comment: Вопросы про один глагол, на на разные темы. Здесь спрашивают, как  по правилу выбрать спряжение глагола, почему глагол не относится к исключениям.   Я против того, чтобы объединять вопросы, темы  совершенно разные. Автор  хочет получить конкретный ответ на СВОЙ вопрос, а не на ЧУЖОЙ.

Answer (score 0):

На сайте Грамота-ру указано, что слово ***гложить*** отсутствует, но есть глагол ***глодать*** (на АТЬ, 1-е спряжение, окончания ЕТ, ЕМ, ЕШЬ, ЕТЕ).

***Глодать — гложет,*** это обычное чередование Д/Ж, Г/Ж, З/Ж перед Е, сравнить: ***брызгать — брызжет, резать — режет***.

**ГЛОДАТЬ,** **гложу,** **гложешь** и **(разг.)** -аю, -аешь; глоданный; -дан, -а, -о; гложа и глодая; нсв. 1. что. Грызть, обкусывая со всех сторон мякоть. Г. кость, кости (обычно о собаке или человеке). Зайцы гложут кору. Кот глодал рыбий хвост. 2. кого-что. Мучить, терзать (о чувствах). **Зависть, ревность гложет кого-л. Тоска сердце гложет.**

Полная парадигма Зализняка https://slovar.cc/rus/zaliznyak/1483829.html

Answer (score 0):

По весьма логичной версии, изложенной в Викисловаре, глагол **глодать** (в источнике представлены формы его изменения по временам и лицам) имеет различающиеся формы для *прямого* и *переносного* смысла в настоящем времени и в повелительном наклонении (**глодает/гложет**, **глодай/гложИ** и т. п.). Разделение распространяется на производные  причастия и деепричастия настоящего времени (есть также различия в возможности образования страдательных форм), а инфинитив (его форма единственна) и прошедшее время глагола такое разделение не затрагивает.

Comment: У нас есть ряд глаголов с разными формами спряжения: движет и двигает, брызжет и брызгает, каплет и капает, колышет и колыхает, мучит и мучает, мечет и метает. Обычно говорят об их семантических или стилевых различиях, но что-то я не слышала версий о прямом и переносном смысле, мне такое толкование не представляется корректным. В паре гложет и глодает различие стилевое.

Comment: Другой пример разделения форм по смыслам: мужи/мужья, сына/сыновья. Нельзя ведь сказать "его глодает ощущение". Другое дело, что некоторые из форм малоупотребимы ("гложи его, пока не сдастся").

Comment: Голой кости и собака не гложет. Именно не гложет, а не глодает. Кажется, "глодает" вообще изгнано из литературного языка.

Comment: Судя по орфоэпическому словарю трудностей (Горбачевич, 2008), из-за Собаки не до конца такое разделение оформилось: для прямого смысла допускаются обе версии (гложет/глодает, гложу/глодаю), для переносного - только "гложет" ("/тоска/ глодает" названо неправильным).

Comment: А Вы верите всем словарям?  Скорее, правильно так:   допускается, но уже не пропускается. Так что собака - это тоже показатель.

Comment: С Собакой во _всех_ словарях считаются из уважения к Далю, с ней ничего не поделать. Видимо, от неё стали отталкиваться при очередном циркулярном обобщении, если заметна тенденция отменить "допущения".